# how to connect (2 way) slack and a meteor app

Tags: meteor, slack-api, slack

I have a meteor app with a fully functiona UI which I would like to integrate with slack.

The integration would need to go 2 ways:

- receive commands from slack
- post answers to those commands to slack

to post to slack I found this: http://blog.differential.com/setting-up-your-meteor-app-to-post-to-slack/

but I haven't yet found anything for the opposite. Tipycally it's very easy (just setup a `POST` route in your app server and receive api calls from slack) but with meteor I couldn't, since it doesn't use a REST Api but rather the ddp protocol (socket based).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages that will help [add rest endpoints to Meteor apps](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API).
I've used [Restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus) a few times and recommend it.